# Counting half hours in a day in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Continuing my [odyssey of counting half hour intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78189920/count-half-hours-since-midnight-europe-london) I now would like same in Postgres.

Given a table with a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column (which would like be UTC but who knows) I would like to, group by `DATE` and count the rows, then compare that to how many half hour periods *should* be in that day (UK). As before, it can be

- 48 for a normal day
- 46 for a "short" day (clocks to forward)
- 50 for a "long" day (clocks go back)

The dates and groupings and things is fairly easy, and something like this produces the right answer

```sql
select 
  date(
    "foo"."log_timestamp" at time zone 'Europe/London'
  ) as "day", 
  (
    date(
      "foo"."log_timestamp" at time zone 'Europe/London'
    ) + interval '1' day
  ) at time zone 'Europe/London' as tomorrow, 
  date(
    "foo"."log_timestamp" at time zone 'Europe/London'
  ) at time zone 'Europe/London' as today, 
  extract(
    epoch 
    from 
      (
        (
          (
            date(
              "foo"."log_timestamp" at time zone 'Europe/London'
            ) + interval '1' day
          ) at time zone 'Europe/London'
        ) - (
          date(
            "foo"."log_timestamp" at time zone 'Europe/London'
          ) at time zone 'Europe/London'
        )
      )
  ) / 1800 as duration 
from 
  "foo"
```

---

Now the interesting part. My understanding is that `DATE + INTEGER` is *equivalent to* `DATE + INTERVAL` for days, however the following

```sql
select 
  "day", 
  ("day" + interval '1' day) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' as tomorrow, 
  "day" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' as today, 
  (
    extract(
      epoch 
      from 
        (
          ("day" + interval '1' day) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' - "day" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'
        )
    ) / 1800
  ), 
  (
    extract(
      epoch 
      from 
        (
          ("day" + 1) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' - "day" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'
        )
    ) / 1800
  ) 
from 
  (
    select 
      '2024-03-31' :: date as "day"
  )
```

Produces

```
2024-03-31,2024-03-31 23:00:00.000000 +00:00,2024-03-31 00:00:00.000000,46,50
```

i.e. `+ interval '1' day` produces a different answer to `+ 1`.

What gives?

---

Running in Docker with `postgres:latest` - `postgres (PostgreSQL) 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2)`

Comment: DST gives. Per [Interval output](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT): *Internally interval values are stored as months, days, and microseconds. This is done because the number of days in a month varies, and a day can have 23 or 25 hours if a daylight savings time adjustment is involved.*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver intriguing - I had assumed that a `DATE` would have no `TZ` and so adding 1 day to it would be the same regardless - [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) seem to imply that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `timezone` must be `UTC`.

```
set timezone = 'UTC';

select '2024-03-31' :: date + interval '1 day';
   ?column?       
---------------------
 2024-04-01 00:00:00

select ('2024-03-31' :: date + interval '1 day')  AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' as tomorrow;
        tomorrow        
------------------------
 2024-03-31 23:00:00+00
```

From here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

> date + interval → timestamp

Therefore you now have a `timestamp`.

Then you apply `AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'` which per:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT

> timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE zone → timestamp with time zone

converts it to a `timestamptz` which when displayed rotates to the server time zone of `UTC`.

Comment: Ooof. How would I go about making my query independent of the server's TZ?

Comment: I am not sure you can as yesterday,  today, tomorrow are relative to what time zone you are in. You might add to your question a more detailed explanation of what you want to achieve. Also a true `date` value will not a have time zone component.

Comment: Will update when I get a chance - but the problem statement is essentially "_given a point on the timeline, determine the number of half hours in the day that corresponds to that point in a particular timezone_". e.g. given an epoch second value, map it to a UK date and give me the half hour periods on that date. It should be agnostic to the timezone of the machine running the query ... ideally.

Comment: @BoristheSpider. What you are seeing now is not tied to the OS time zone, it is dependent on the Postgres server `timezone`. The easiest way I could see to do this is do `set timezone = 'Europe/London';` at the beginning of a session and then do the calculations. Then everything would be relative to 'Europe/London'.